# TypeORM createQueryBuilder can't manage a JOIN

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, typeorm

I'm new with TypeORM.
I'm working with node, typescript, TypeORM, and MySQL.
I can't figure out how JOIN and createQueryBuilder works in TypeORM.

I have a Response table with a user_id field, that matchs with an User table an its id field.
The relation is response.user_id = user.id, in a One to Many relation.
And I don't know how it works with TypeORM

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryColumn, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, OneToMany } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from '../User/User';

@Entity("response")
export class Response {

  @PrimaryColumn("varchar", { length: 80, unique: true, primary: true })
  public id: string;

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public bk_id: number;

  @Column("varchar", { length: 80 })
  public user_id: string;

  @Column("varchar", { length: 80 })
  public parent_request_id: string;

  @Column("text")
  public description: string;

  @Column("integer")
  public status_id: number;  

  @Column("integer")
  public deleted: number;

  @Column("timestamp")
  public created_on: Date;

  @Column("timestamp")
  public last_update: Date;

  @OneToMany(type => User, user => user.id)
    users: User[];
}
```

And User:

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryColumn, ManyToOne } from 'typeorm';
import { Response } from '../Response/Response';

@Entity("user")
export class User {

  @PrimaryColumn("varchar", { length: 50, unique: true, primary: true })
  public id: string;

  @Column("varchar", { length: 255, unique: true })
  public username: string;

  @Column("varchar", { length: 255 })
  public password: string;

  @Column("varchar", { length: 150 })
  public first_name: string;

  @Column("varchar", { length: 255 })
  public last_name: string;

  @Column("varchar", { length: 355, unique: true })
  public email: string;
  
  @Column("timestamp")
  public created_on: Date;

  @Column("integer")
  public userstatus_id: number;  

  @Column("integer")
  public deleted: number;

  @Column("timestamp")
  public last_login: Date;

  @ManyToOne(type => Response, response => response.user_id)
  response: Response;
}
```

And my Sql sentence looks like this:

```
   const result = await this.entityManager
   .createQueryBuilder('Response')
   .leftJoinAndSelect(
     'Response.user_id',
     'user',
     'user.id = :id',
     { id: 'user_id' },
   )
   .where('response.parent_request_id = :parent_request_id', { parentRequestId });
```

I'm getting the error:

```
"Response" alias was not found. Maybe you forgot to join it?
```

Appreciate any help.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because of:

```
const result = await this.entityManager
.createQueryBuilder('Response') // << entity with '' and lacking alias
.leftJoinAndSelect(
  'Response.user_id',
  'user',
  'user.id = :id',
  { id: 'user_id' }, // < with '' would set as string (user_id)
)
.where('response.parent_request_id = :parent_request_id', { parentRequestId }); // < you forgot to declare param
```

You can try the following:

```
const result = await this.entityManager
.createQueryBuilder(Response, 'response')
.leftJoinAndSelect(
  'response.user_id',
  'user',
  'user.id = :id',
  { id: user_id }, // assuming you're using user_id as variable
)
.where('response.parent_request_id = :parent_request_id', { parent_request_id: parentRequestId });
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution wasn't working for me, so I'm in a hurry and I prefer to build it with the SQL query.

Comment: If you're using `user_id` from `response.user_id` then you can use`user.id = response.user_id`

Answer (score 1):

I have finally used the Sql Query, and not the Query builder.
I think is very tricky the construction of the query builder, so I prefer to have all in my hand. This is my solution:

```
this.entityManager.query(
        `SELECT r.*, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.email, u.deleted, u.username, u.userstatus_id FROM knowhow.response as r
        LEFT JOIN user as u on u.id = r.user_id
        WHERE r.parent_request_id = '${parentRequestId}'`
```